# how to solve this using while loop php

Tags: php, html, loops

can anyone help me in making a table like the one below using PHP HTML code? seems to use looping and calculation formulas.
I've tried coding but I'm stuck and have no more ideas until here, (please understand that I'm a newbie :"D)

```
    <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Val1</th>
                <th>Val2</th>
            </thead>
<?php
$no=1;
$qty=6;
$val1=1;
while($no<=4){
?>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $qty; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $val1; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $val1+$qty-1 ?></td>
                </tr>
<?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

[image]

column assumption:

1. No: running number
2. Qty: the value that determines the calculation of the Val2 column
3. Val1: the first value / first row is determined by yourself, for the next value 1 is added from the value in the previous Val2 row.
4. Val2: Qty + Val1 (one line)

expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, there is several things missing from your code.

1. Move the  from loop
2. Add changes to the variables in code, so they update every time the loop is executed.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Val1</th>
        <th>Val2</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            $qty = 6;
            $val1 = 1;
            $no = 1;
            while($no<=4) {
               $val2 = $qty * $no;
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $qty; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $val1; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $val2; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
               $val1 += $qty;
               $no++;                
            } 
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```